# How to document unlimited argument parameters?

Tags: php, documentation, documentation-generation

In PHP you can have a function take an infinite number of arguments like

```
  /**
   * Do abc...
   *
   * @since   1.0
   * @param   mixed $arg1       Arg description
   * @return  string            Results
   */
function abc($arg1 = null){
  $args = func_get_args();
  // do smth with $args
}
```

How should I illustrate this in my DocBlock ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[phpdoc.org manual example](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.param.pkg.html):

```
/**
 * @param mixed $varname,... unlimited OPTIONAL number of additional variables [...]
 */
```

> You may document parameters listed or any optional paramters that will
>   be parsed by standard PHP functions func_num_args()/get_func_arg().
>   Recommended name format for parameters listed with func_get_arg() is:
>
> - $paramname if there is only one parameter
> - $paramname,... if the number of parameters is unlimited
>
> phpDocumentor will display the optional description unmodified.
>
> Note that the $paramname,... will be shown in the output docs in both
>   the parameter listing AND the function signature. If you are not
>   indicating in the actual code that the parameter is optional (via
>   "$paramname = 'a default value'"), then you should mention in the
>   parameter's description that the parameter is optional.